# XdmNode.Children(uri, localname) not returning results

Tags: saxon

I'm trying to get all child XdmNodes of a node using node.Children(uri, localName), but I receive an empty list. At the same time enumerating the node.Children() returns correct results.

Is this a bug?

Best regards,
Petko Stoyanov

Code example 1: not working

```
var href = record.Children(WellKnownXmlNamespace.XInclude, "include").First().GetAttributeValue("href");
```

Code example 2: working

```
var href = record.Children().First(
                    p => p.NodeKind == XmlNodeType.Element 
                            && WellKnownXmlNamespace.XInclude.Equals(p.NodeName.Uri) 
                            && "include".Equals(p.NodeName.LocalName))
                    .GetAttributeValue("href");
```

Code example 3: working

```
var enumerator = record.EnumerateAxis(XdmAxis.Child, new QName(WellKnownXmlNamespace.XInclude, "include"));
enumerator.MoveNext();
var href = enumerator.Current.GetAttributeValue("href");
```

The complete XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recordSeries xmlns="uri:rs" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <record number="R0001">
      <xi:include href="r0001.xml"/>
    </record>
</recordSeries>
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking this is Saxon.NET 10.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a bug if I understand the API correctly, the selection

```
       var href = record.Select(Steps.Child("http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude", "include")).First().GetAttributeValue("href");
```

works, as does

```
       record.Children("include").First().GetAttributeValue("href");
```

while

```
       record.Children("http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude", "include").First().GetAttributeValue("href");
```

does not work. Tested with Saxon .NET HE 10.5.1.

So the bug is in `public IEnumerable<XdmNode> Children(String uri, String localName)`  https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/saxon10/entry/src/main/csharp/api/Saxon.Api/Model.cs#L2456 doing `return Children().SelectMany(Steps.Child(uri, localName).Func);` which basically tries to select grandchildren of the namespace uri and local name.

Perhaps you can use an extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<XdmNode> Children2(this XdmNode node, string ns, string localName)
{
    return Steps.Child(ns, localName).Func.Invoke(node);
}
```

for the time until the bug will have been fixed.

Or the `record.Select(Steps.Child("http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude", "include"))` I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It is interesting that recordSeries.Children("uri:rs", "record") on the root node works fine.

Comment: @PetkoStoyanov, yes, seems odd, let's see what Saxonica find.

Comment: Hi, I am struggling to reproduce the reported problem. Is it possible you can update the bug issue with a full repo. I created a nunit test case and I get the `href`  attribute as expected. The question now is did the user correctly navigate to the `record` element?

Answer (score 0):

Raised as a bug here:

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5005

Please monitor that issue to track resolution.

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been committed to the bug issue. As a workaround the user can use the method Children(IPredicate filter) with their own predicate to filter on the ns and local name. See example below which would work:

```
    static IPredicate<XdmNode> ExpandedNamePredicate(String ns, String local)
    {
        return new Predicate<XdmNode>(item =>
        {
            if (!(item is XdmNode)) { return false; }
            XdmNode node = (XdmNode)item;
            return node.NodeKind == XmlNodeType.Element
                    && node.NodeName.LocalName.Equals(local) && node.NodeName.Uri.Equals(ns);
        });
    }


   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processor = new Processor();

        var docBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

        var doc = docBuilder.Build(new Uri(new Uri(AppContext.BaseDirectory), "XMLFile1.xml"));

        var record = doc.Select(Steps.Descendant("record")).First();

        Console.WriteLine(record);

        var include = record.Children(ExpandedNamePredicate("http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude", "include")).First();

        Console.WriteLine(include);

        var href = include.GetAttributeValue("href");

        Console.WriteLine(href);

    }
```